# pgAdmin Запрос базы данных

Tags: sql

Переношу схему с одной базы в другую.
При выполнении SQL запроса в новой, получаю ошибку: `ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "INCLUDE")`

Строка `ADD CONSTRAINT ucode UNIQUE (code) INCLUDE (id, description);`

Comment: Проверьте версию базы. `INCLUDE` в синтаксисе индексов добавлен в postgresql 11. На более старых очевидно не будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо, и правда версии разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Перенесу из комментария в ответы)

По состоянию на лето 2019 года синтаксис [`INCLUDE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createindex.html) для размещения в листьях дерева индекса дополнительных данных ещё достаточно новый, был добавлен только в релизе postgresql 11. Поэтому наиболее вероятная причина ошибки - база, в которую вы переносите схему, недостаточно новой версии.

PS: кстати упомянуть, `desription` выглядит как довольно объёмное поле и я сомневаюсь, что разумно его дублировать в индексе ради `index-only scan`. Возможно значительно возросший размер индекса сведёт на ноль весь гипотетический смысл операции.